# Changing a table box to an input field

Tags: jquery, html, pdo

I'm creating a table for an editable contact formula. The contacts get fetched from a database and get put into the table. Then I want to be able to click on one of the tableboxes (i.e. "Name"), which switches the box to an input field so I can edit the info and save it.

My table looks like this:

```
<?php while($dsk=$stmk->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
  <tr>
    <td><p id="termin" onclick="hide()"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Termin']); ?></p><input id="intermin" class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Termin']); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Name']); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Vorname']); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Geburtsdatum']); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Beruf']); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Telefon']); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Info']); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Anrufe']); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Art']); ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I'm trying it out for the 1 row for now

The jQuery looks like this:

```
<script (document).getElementById(id+"p").onclick = function hide(){
            $("#termin").hide();
            $("#intermin").show().focus();
        };
        $("#intermin").focusout = function() {
            $("#intermin").hide();
            $("#termin").show();
        };
});></script>
```

The input is hidden per ccs with `<style>.edit-input {display:none;}</style>`

It's not working though. The input is hidden but when I click on the "Termin" box nothing happens. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: None of the tds or inputs have ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put simple logic to have `<p>` and it's respective editable `input` field. Put class="label-input" for `<p>` and class="edit-input" for respective input and build up your logic around it.

see below code -

```
<?php while($dsk=$stmk->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Termin']); ?></p>
        <input class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Termin']); ?>" style="display:none"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Name']); ?></p>
        <input class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Name']); ?>" style="display:none"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Vorname']); ?></p>
        <input class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Vorname']); ?>" style="display:none"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Geburtsdatum']); ?></p>
        <input class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Geburtsdatum']); ?>" style="display:none"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Beruf']); ?></p>
        <input class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Beruf']); ?>" style="display:none"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Telefon']); ?></p>
        <input class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Telefon']); ?>" style="display:none"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Info']); ?></p>
        <input class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Info']); ?>" style="display:none"/>
      </td>
      <td>
         <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Anrufe']); ?></p>
         <input class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Anrufe']); ?>" style="display:none"/>
      </td>
      <td>
          <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Art']); ?></p>
          <input class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Art']); ?>" style="display:none"/>
      </td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.label-input', function(){
       $(this).hide();
       var $input = $(this).next('.edit-input')
       $input.show();
       $input.focus();
    });

     $(document).on('focusout', '.edit-input', function(){
       $(this).hide();
       var $label = $(this).prev('.label-input');
       $label.text($(this).val());
       $label.show();
     });
  });
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u7ofjprw/87/)**

Comment: looks real good, doesnt work either tho. the input is hidden nothing happens on click tho

Comment: my bad. I have corrected the jquery script now. please try

Comment: forgot to apply new value to `p` element. Also, add display:none style to input initially. I have updated my post and added working jsfiddle also. pls take a look

Comment: it is working on jsfiddle also, if it is not working for you then it could be some different issue. can you provide jsfiddle with your issue recreated on it so that i can take a look at it

Comment: well how can i insert php in jsfiddle

Comment: you can copy created html in jsfiddle

Comment: then check your browser console if there is any error due to some other code

Comment: it works, i made a mistake writing script =) thak you!